# white line the height of my button covering the screen

Tags: html, css

Im having this weird issue I cant see adressed anywhere else after searching so im writing here; I've been fiddling with css and html code in JSFiddle recently; (im very new to it so my code probably sucks), but theres this white line crossing most, but not all, of the screen that matches the height of the button and I cant figure out what's causing it. Also, im using scss because SASS seems to break my code and JSFiddle doesn't have autocomplete for it yet.

I searched through the code and I thought at first it was a text problem, but after figuring out how to keep the text within the button wrapped, nothing happened and it was still there. There was nothing on it on google or here from what I could see. Here's the JSFiddle for those who would need it: https://jsfiddle.net/gambian/dav7f30b/11/

```
$color1: #010226;
$color2: #fcdbab;

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;

  border: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: $color1;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: $color1;

  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: bolder;
  color: $color2;

}

.center {
  margin: center;
  text-align: center;
}

:hover {
  border-color: lighten($color1, 10);
}

:active {
  border-color: lighten($color1, 15);
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, peachpuff, coral);
}
```

Comment: I'll also send the HTML code, if for some reason you cant just check the JSFiddle.

Comment: It's the `body` background color. The orange colour should be on the `body` element not on the `<html>` element

Comment: Apply the background to the `body` instead of the `html`. And `margin: center` will not work, you could use `margin: auto`, but it will have no affect as the button is being centred by the `text-align` property in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the body has a white background...

Do not put the background on the html tag but on the body tag.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, peachpuff, coral);
}
```